# Divide a div into many sub-divs 1 pixel each

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi I have a div with 800 px width and 600 px height.
I want to divide it into 800 X 400 = 3,20,000 sub divs.
which means each sub-div with 1 px width and 1 px height.

I am using PHP for that. Here is my **code.**

```
  <div class="main">
    <?php
     for($i=1;$i<=320000;$i++)
     {
    ?>
        <div class="single" ></div>

    <?php
     }
    ?>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:800px;
height:400px;
}
.single
{
background-color:pink;
float:left;
height:1px;
width:1px;
}
```

But when I run the page, it is taking too long to execute the code. and also my browser is crashing sometimes. Is there any easier way to my job? Can I do it with Javascript or jQuery in an easier way?

---

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. THIS IS REPLY FOR THOSE WHO ASK ME WHY I WANTED TO DO SO?

Actually I want to develop a paint like application.

When I drag mouse on each sub-div, the color changes. Here is my complete code

PHP :

```
<div class="main">
<?php 

     for($i=1;$i<=320000;$i++)
     {
    ?>

        <!--<div class="single" onMouseOver="changeColor(this)"></div>-->
        <div class="single" onmousemove="changeColor(this)" ></div>

    <?php
     }

?>
```

CSS :

```
<style>
.single
{
 background-color:pink;
 float:left;
 height:3px;
 width:3px;
 cursor:crosshair;
}
.main
{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:800px;
 height:400px;
}
</style>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
<script>
var isMouseDown = false;
document.onmousedown = function() { isMouseDown = true };
document.onmouseup   = function() { isMouseDown = false };

function changeColor(sing)
{
 if(isMouseDown) 
 {
    sing.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 }

}
</script>
```

And I am on the initial stage. Please do not laugh at my idea!! :P

Comment: First of all, why you want to do that?

Comment: Obviously your complexity is too high...page execution time exceeds and constant computation crashes your browser...use HTML5 techs like canvas read more about it

Comment: this is 320k divs... no wonder it takes time..

Comment: this question has given me an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't surprise me that creating a div for each pixel is going to take a long time.  I would recommend you look into using an html5 canvas instead, you can draw what ever you want on it, pixel by pixel and it is much faster than trying to do divs, not to mention easier.

Answer (score 2):

Creating over 300,000 divs through code will crash your browser even if you've got a very powerful machine. Even if you used JavaScript or jQuery, you'd face the same problems. 
Why do you need to split it up into so many divs?